# Python + OpenCV + Webcam Calibration: Doesn't detect full pattern

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

i am trying to undistort a photo of a laptop screen in order to learn how camera calibration and undistortion with opencv + python work.

On the basis of a camera matrix that i obtained from one photo with controlled content on the screen, i would like to undistort subsequent images.
Neither the camera, nor the display will move, so i think i need only one image for calibration (or is this assumption already completely wrong?)

My first image with controlled content is this 24x13 chessboard. The camera's distortion is nicely visible in the corners of the photo:

[image]

This is the script that i use for calibration and undistortion:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("img.png")
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

def chessboard_objectpoints(boxes_x, boxes_y):
    objp = np.zeros(((boxes_x - 1) * (boxes_y - 1), 3), np.float32)
    objp[:, :2] = np.mgrid[0:boxes_x-1, 0:boxes_y-1].T.reshape(-1, 2)
    return objp

def chessboard_imagepoints(img_gray, boxes_x, boxes_y, out_img=None):
    boxdim = (boxes_x - 1, boxes_y - 1)
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(img_gray, boxdim, None)
    assert ret

    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
    corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(img_gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
    if out_img is not None:
        out_img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(out_img, boxdim, corners2, ret)
    return corners2

BOXES_X = 23 # should be 24
BOXES_Y = 12 # should be 13

obj_points = chessboard_objectpoints(BOXES_X, BOXES_Y)
img_points = chessboard_imagepoints(img_gray, BOXES_X, BOXES_Y, img)

ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(
  [obj_points], [img_points], img_gray.shape[::-1], None, None
)

h, w = img.shape[:2]
dimension = w, h

newcameramtx, roi = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx, dist, dimension, 0)
dst = cv2.undistort(img, mtx, dist)

x, y, w, h = roi
dst = dst[y : y + h, x : x + w]

cv2.imshow("img", dst)
cv2.waitKey()
```

The resulting image of this script is the following, and it is indeed less distorted than the original:

[image]

Now i have 2 questions:

1. Why can `cv2.findChessboardCorners` only find a subset of the corners, see image and sourcecode? I expect it to be able to find a pattern of 23x12 corners, but that won't work.
2. with the smaller subset of the chessboard, there is a lot of remaining distortion, see image. It also doesn't look like the full pattern would really help, then. How do i undistort this kind of image completely?